# How can I create a custom filtered view of questions?

Tags: support, feature-request, search, filtering

How would I create an filtered view of Programmers.SE, like perhaps with a query from the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com)?

The reason I'm looking for this is because when Programmers.SE is active, the front page gets messed up with closed and negatively voted questions.

I'm not interested in why that is, but just about making the front page less noisy.

Since we can favorite and ignore tags, perhaps setting up a tag would be a possible solution. Or would it be a disruption?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to create another filter that'll show up on the site, but you could create a search and bookmark the URL in your browser of choice.

For example, this will show all open questions with score 0 or more, sorted by activity. So it's basically like an active sort for the front page but only for non-negatively scored open questions:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=closed%3a0%20votes%3a0

You can read about additional search options [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Though, a bookmark, anyone like to use that instead of reshing startpage/alter filter buttons?